# How can I use command to open the first search result with vi?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

Every time I need  to find a file and then open it, I have to use :
find ./ -name ****.properties. , then copy the result, and then vi "paste the result here"  .
If I need to use a mouse, it can be a little trouble.  So is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Is it possible to open the second file only ?

Comment: find ./ -name *properties | head -2 | tail -1
I think this is not that good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open an arbitrary file by using AWK or sed to print a particular line number.

```
vi "$(find ./ -name **.properties | awk 'NR==2')"
```

or

```
vi "$(find ./ -name **.properties | awk 'NR==2{print;quit}')"
```

or

```
vi "$(find ./ -name **.properties | sed -n '2p')"
```

or

```
vi "$(find ./ -name **.properties | sed -n '2{p;q}')"
```

The versions with `quit` or `q` return a little quicker if there is a large number of files.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name \*.properties | xargs -d '\n' vi
```

will open all files in a single `vi` instance.  To open just the first, use

```
find . -name \*.properties | head -1 | xargs -d '\n' vi
```

Comment: With GNU findutils, `find . -name '*.properties' -exec vi '{}' +` will do the first.

Comment: Is it possible to open only second file ?

Comment: @ephemient: no it won't.

Comment: @Foolish: Sure: `find . -name \*.properties | head -2 | tail -1 | xargs -d '\n' vi`

Comment: What do you mean "no it won't"?  Works fine here, with GNU findutils 4.5.9.

Comment: How many vims will be running?

Comment: One single `vim`.  For GNU findutils, that's the difference between `-exec ... +` and `-exec ... ;`.

Comment: Whoops ... I missed the `+`.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

If you change your shell to zsh, you'll need `find` a lot less often, as zsh allows you to do most of what `find` can do through globbing. To start with, `**/` has a special meaning: `**/foo` expands to files called `foo` in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively, i.e. it matches the same files as `find . -name foo`. So you can edit all matches with

```
vi **/*.properties
```

Since bash 4.0, if you put `shopt -s globstar` in your `~/.bashrc`, `**/` behaves in the same way.

In zsh, you have a lot more possibilities thanks to glob qualifiers (described very tersely near the end of the [`zshexpn` man page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/zshexpn1.html)). The principle is to restrict the matches by adding one or more qualifiers in parentheses after the match. For example, the qualifier `.` restricts to regular files, while `/` restricts to directories. The qualifier `[1]` retains only the first match; `[1,4]` retains the first four matches; and so on. For example, to edit the first (in full path lexicographic order) regular file matching `*.properties`:

```
vi **/*.properties(.[1])
```

If you'd rather edit the most recently modified matching file, you can use the `om` qualifier to sort the matches by modification times (in order of increasing age):

```
vi **/*.properties(.om[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `-quit` option for the `find` command. The following could be an example of what you want to accomplish:

```
find . -name "*.properties" -print -exec vi {} \; -quit
```

I should point out that, as I discovered not long after I posted this answer, the `-quit` switch does not exist for the BSD version of the `find` command, what you are likely to find, for example, on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I think someone has shown the answer:

> find -name *.properties -exec vi {} \;

this will case a sequence of editing the files which are find by "find -name *.properties".

If you just want to open the second file:

> vi "$(find -name *.properties | awk 'NR==2')"

Answer (score 0):

`find . -name "*.properties" -exec vi {} \;`

Then use the interrupt key (e.g. ^C) after editing the first file.

Comment: That will open a vi for each file found, in sequence.

Comment: True, am upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the results of the `find` command into the command line for `vi` like this:

```
vi $(find . -name \*.properties -print)
```

or like this:

```
vi $(find -name \*.properties)
```

since `.` and `-print` are implied if omitted. To open just the first result, use

```
vi $(find -name \*.properties | head -1)
```

Comment: is it possible to open the second result only ? I tried Head -2, but it will open both first and second files

Comment: Please be aware that this syntax is specific to certain shells such as `bash` and `ksh`.